# SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'hr.staff' doesn't exist

Tags: php, laravel, database, laravel-8

Hye everyone! I want to make CRUD but I have an error when try to submit the form. The error shows, "***SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'hr.staff'
doesn't exist***". Below shows my database structure and my coding.

**Staff Model:-**

```
    class Staffs extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'staffid', 'address', 'religion', 'email', 'phonenum', 'maritalstatus'
    ];
}
```

**Staffs Migration table:-**

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('staffs', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->string('name');
        $table->integer('staffid');
        $table->string('address');
        $table->string('religion');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->integer('phonenum');
        $table->string('maritalstatus');
    });
}
```

**StaffContoller:-**

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        'name' => 'required',
        'staffid' => 'required',
        'address' => 'required',
        'religion' => 'required',
        'email' => 'required',
        'phonenum' => 'required',
        'maritalstatus' => 'required',
    ]);

    Staff::create($request->all());
 
    return redirect()->route('staffs.index')
                    ->with('success','Staff data has been created successfully.');
}
```

**addstaff.blade.php:-**

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('staffs.store') }}">
                    @csrf
                    <div class="grid grid-cols-2 gap-6">
                        <div class="grid grid-rows-2 gap-6">
                            <div>
                                <x-label for="name" :value="__('Name:')" />
                                <x-input id="name" class="block mt-1 w-full" type="text" name="name" value="{{ old('name') }}" autofocus />
                            </div>

                            <div>
                                <x-label for="staffid" :value="__('Staff ID:')" />
                                <x-input id="staffid" class="block mt-1 w-full" type="integer" name="staffid" value="{{ old('staffid') }}" autofocus />
                            </div>

<div class="flex items-center justify-end mt-4">
                            <x-button class="ml-3">
                                {{ __('Submit') }}
                            </x-button>
                        </div>
```

P/s: Can't paste the full form of submit but all the field is there.

**Database Structure:-**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your table name is `staffs` not `staff`.

`SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'hr.staff' doesn't exist`

Update your model's `$table` property to the correct table name, then you should be able to use this model to create a record. `Staff::create($request->all());`

Comment: already rename the model name and got this error, "SQLSTATE[22003]: Numeric value out of range: 1264 Out of range value for column 'phonenum' at row 1"

Comment: @Daisy post your `Staff` model and migration.

Comment: done update the question

Comment: i try again to submit and get this error, "SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1366 Incorrect integer value: 'XL212863' for column `hr`.`staffs`.`staffid` at row 1 " But why the validation did not come, why the validation error come after i click the submit button. huhuhuhu

Comment: @Daisy `'XL212863'` is not an integer. Change `$table->integer('staffid');` to `$table->string('staffid');` in your migration.

Comment: done edit but got this error, "SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1366 Incorrect integer value: 'XL212863' for column `hr`.`staffs`.`staffid` at row 1 (SQL: insert into `staffs` (`name`, `staffid`, `address`, `religion`, `email`, `phonenum`, `maritalstatus`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (AddaAj, XL212863, puchong, Muslim, adaaj@gmail.com, 0166992493, Married, 2021-11-10 04:05:20, 2021-11-10 04:05:20))"

Comment: @Daisy did you run `php artisan migrate:refresh` to rebuild the table with the new column definitions?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239062/discussion-between-daisy-and-bassxzero).